# Tableau long number converting to scientific

Tags: string, tableau-api, long-integer, number-formatting, scientific-notation

I have a field which contains 50digits as a number format. In excel all 50 digits are displayed but when I load this to Tableau, the number gets converted in scientific format. I tried changing the data type of the field in Excel as Text and in Tableau I changed it to string but it still shows in scientific format. 
Excel:

7091053585214305444451810524505546820833

Tableau :

7.09105e+39

I want the field to be in string format and display all the digits.

Can anyone please suggest what can I do here?

Comment: Tableau has several resources on their website for this issue. Check out https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/importing-large-number-as-string-results-in-scientific-notation and https://community.tableau.com/thread/242731.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change format of the date to text in excel then it will still retain the exp format, since you have access to excel data source, create a new column and change the format of the column to `Text` then copy the data into that column which will consider it as Text instead of Integer.

[image]